# Befuddled (adj) VS Fuddled(adj)

Tags: vocabulary

What is the difference between these two adjectives- befuddled and fuddled? Can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: Just because you see a word in the dictionary (or, for that matter, if you see a word that has variant forms in the dictionary) doesn't mean that it is common and would necessarily be understood by native speakers. Yes, *fuddled* and *befuddled* mean the exact same thing, but if you spent a year in the United States, I bet you wouldn't hear someone say *fuddled*, but I bet you would hear someone say *befuddled*.

Comment: I saw this word in a novel. Here's the line- "The fuddled young husband stared for a few seconds at this unexpected praise of his wife, half in doubt of the wisdom of his own attitude towards the possessor of such qualities."

Comment: As I've said below, I have **read** the word *fuddled* before, which is how I know of it; however, I have only heard someone ever say **befuddled**. I've looked it up though and **fuddled** is the older form by more than three centuries, so that may be the reason--it is becoming archaic perhaps or obsolete since **befuddled** took its primary place in the 19th century.

Answer (score 1):

"**befuddled**" is the more common word but mostly they are interchangeable and both mean "*confused*". However, "**[fuddled](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fuddled)**" mostly means "*confused or stupefied, especially as a result of drinking alcohol*".

Comment: I want to say that "befuddled" is confused due to exterior circumstances while "fuddled" is confused due to interior circumstances  (drunkedness in this case).  They overlap enough that you could easily interchange them I think.

Comment: @Neil I'm not a native speaker, but I wouldn't, for a reason, distinguish them this way, since '**getting drunk**' is really an exterior circumstance.

Comment: Yes the act itself is exterior, but the effect is due to an internal cause (high blood alcohol levels).  In any case, just contributing my personal opinion, being a native speaker myself.

Comment: I have only seen **fuddled** as a verb or any other form in written English; I have never once heard it said (from memory) whereas I have heard and read **befuddled** many, many times. I would stick with **befuddled**. They are interchangeable, but pick the one that is used the most by native speakers lest you lose the meaning of your sentence.

Comment: Thanks guys. Much appreciated.  For reference, I saw this word in a novel by Thomas Hardy named "The Mayor of Casterbridge". Here's the line- "The fuddled young husband stared for a few seconds at this unexpected praise of his wife, half in doubt of the wisdom of his own attitude towards the possessor of such qualities."